# Android Access TextView Value On RecyclerView Item Click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to access a RecyclerView textview value on RecyclerView item click. I have tried with below code but it is giving a `NullPointerException` Error.

```
 holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {

                Log.e("value: ",holder.tvTextview.getText().toString());
  }
  });
```

How can I access this value

Comment: Can you provide more context? How does your adapter create the ViewHolders? Are you sure that `holder.tvTextview` points to an actual View? What is the NullPointerException saying is null?

Comment: please share your code

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BranchListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BranchListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<BranchListModel> mData;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private ItemClickListener mClickListener;
    Context context;
    String animal;
    BranchListModel currentItem;


    // data is passed into the constructor
   public BranchListAdapter(Context context, List<BranchListModel> data, ItemClickListener mClickListener) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mData = data;
        this.context = context;
        this.mClickListener = mClickListener;
    }

    // inflates the row layout from xml when needed
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.select_brnach_item_design, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


        currentItem = mData.get(position);
        holder.txtproductname.setText(currentItem.getBrachName());
        animal = currentItem.getBranchID();
    }

    // binds the data to the TextView in each row

    // total number of rows
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }




    // stores and recycles views as they are scrolled off screen
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView txtproductname;
        ConstraintLayout relativeLayout;



        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            txtproductname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtBranchname);
//            datenumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dateNumber);
            relativeLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.myItemLayout);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mClickListener != null) {
                mClickListener.onItemClick(view, getAdapterPosition(), mData.get(getAdapterPosition()).getBranchID());
                animal ="";
            }

            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }

    // convenience method for getting data at click position
    public String getItem(int id) {
        return String.valueOf(mData.get(id));
    }

    // allows clicks events to be caught
    public void setClickListener(ItemClickListener itemClickListener) {
//       this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
       this.mClickListener = itemClickListener;
    }

    // parent activity will implement this method to respond to click events
    public interface ItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(View view, int position, String animal);
    }

}
```

Change your Adapter class like this and set the on click in activity

```
 @Override
    public void onItemClick(View view, int position, String animal) {

//        Toast.makeText(this, ""+animal, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        GlobalData.setBrachID(animal);

        Intent i = new Intent(this,NomineeInfoActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
```